# Xamarin - SQLite.SQLiteException: malformed database schema

Tags: xamarin.android, sqlite-net

I am trying to set password to my database in Xamarin.Android project here is sample of my code after include [Sqlcipher](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_sqlcipher/)

First install works just fine but when I close app and re-open it , app crashes with this error

```
SQLite3.Prepare2
android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: SQLite.SQLiteException: malformed database schema (Items) - unrecognized token: "]"
```

my sample code

```
private async void CreateDb()
        {
            string requireFlag = SharedPreManager<string>.GetSingleton(this).RetrieveAccessKey(DSPPublicKeys.REQUIRE_ALTER_KEY, "true").ToString();
            //Creating database, if it doesn't already exist 
            if (!File.Exists(_dbPath))
            {
         await _logic.CreateDb(_dbPath);
            }
            else if (File.Exists(_dbPath) && DSPPublicKeys.REQUIRE_ALTER_Client && requireFlag.Equals("true"))
            {
                DeleteDb();
                await _logic.CreateDb(_dbPath);
                SharedPreManager<string>.GetSingleton(this).SaveAccessKey(DSPPublicKeys.REQUIRE_ALTER_KEY, "false");
            }
            if (db == null)
            {
        db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(_dbPath);
            }
          // set password to database 
         var t = db.QueryAsync<int>("PRAGMA key=123456").Wait(-1);

        if (NetworkUtils.IsNetworkConnected(ApplicationContext))
             _logic.MigrateDataFromBackend(db);
        }
```

Table definition

```
[Table("Items")]
    public class Item 
    {
        [PrimaryKey , Column("ID")]
        public long ID { get; set; }
        [Column("TradeNameEn")]
        public string TradeNameEn { get; set; }
        [Column("TradeNameNative")]
        public string TradeNameNative { get; set; }
        [Column("GenericName")]
        public string GenericName { get; set; }
        [Column("TimeStamp")]
        public long TimeStamp { get; set; }
        [Column("BaseUnitPrice")]
        public decimal BaseUnitPrice { get; set; }


    }
```

any one can guide me why this error raised here

Comment: What is `Items`?

Comment: it is table of items   db.CreateTable<Items>();

Comment: What is the table definition?

Comment: I update my question please check , note every thing was working before set password to my database

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue @MinaFawzy